# CLibraryError: error parsing unit database

Tags: python, c, database, import, anaconda

I'm using a software called `visan`. It's actually a python-module and installable via conda with `conda install -c stcorp visan`. It comes with a gui and seems to be great for working with remote sensing data. When I use a function from the package `harp` to import data it always throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/visan/lib/python3.7/site-packages/harp/_harppy.py", line 1134, in import_product
    raise CLibraryError()
harp._harppy.CLibraryError: error parsing unit database (/home/user/miniconda3/envs/visan/share/harp/udunits2.xml)
```

If it matters: I'm using ubuntu 18.04;) I can however start `python` from bash and import and call `harp.import_product` without a problem. Though I don't know how to use sume functionality from the command line (e.g. the function `wplot`). I'm a little lost how to approach this error:/

Comment: what are exactly trying to do?